# Link container Registered Type with Shell window title

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have a Prims MVVM application that was using the Bootstrapper class to start the application and main window. Bootstrapper was depreciated so I switched it over to be a PrismApplication. I have added a class that wraps serial communication and exposes events that are triggered when the serial class states change (e.g. connected, disconnected etc). To instantiate this component, I am using RegisterSingleton:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {            
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMessages, MessageBuilder>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<AbstractLibSerial, LibSerialVariant1>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(SettingsModel));
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);            

        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(MainModule.MainModule));
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(SettingsModule.SettingsModule));            
    }

    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return (Window)new Shell();    
    }
}
```

Shell.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="VibeOR.Desktop.Shell"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VibeOR.Desktop"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Vibe Base Station" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <ContentControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
```

When I run the applicaiton, I see that RegisterTypes is called before CreateShell so I was hoping to that I could link the events from the instantiated LibSerialVariant1 singleton to the title window from the Shell class. However, you can see in the code above that I am manually instantiating the shell (new Shell()). I'm not sure how I would get access to the container registered types to link them with the newly instantiated shell object?

Any input would be grand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To instantiate this component, I am using `RegisterSingleton`

This looks like a misunderstanding - registering a type will *not* create an instance.

If you want the singleton to be created and registered, you can register an instance (instances are always singletons):

```
_container.RegisterInstance<IInterface>( _container.Resolve<Implementation>() );
```

But you have to be careful with this, because there's no way to guarantee that all the dependencies of `Implementation` are registered yet (they might come from other modules).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Haukinger! I now instantiate LibSerial in the main App and wired the events into the Shell class using standard windows events (because Shell is based on the Window class).

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    private AbstractLibSerial _lib;

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {            
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMessageBuilder, MessageBuilderVariant1>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<AbstractLibSerial, LibSerialVariant1>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(SettingsModel));
        var _container = containerRegistry.GetContainer();
        _lib = _container.Resolve<LibSerialVariant1>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<AbstractLibSerial>(_lib);
    }
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);            


        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(MainModule.MainModule));
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(SettingsModule.SettingsModule));            
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell(Window shell)
    {
        base.InitializeShell(shell);
        _lib.SerialEvent += ((Shell)shell).OnSerialEvent;
    }
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return (Window)new Shell();
    }

}
```